# Redis Server 3.0 : (error) ERR max number of clients reached ubuntu 16

Tags: redis

I have run out of idea on this error on my ubuntu 16 server. i think i have configured everything. everything is manually installed and configured.

I have set the redis max-clients configuration to 100000, file descriptor to 100000, set all the sysctl to allow many tcp connections but i still got the same error.

Redis Info:

Redis server v=3.0.6 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=687a2a319020fa42

tcp-keepalive 60 timeout 300 max-clients 100000

No matter how i try to change configuration, the same result will occur if it reach 4000++ connections.

do you guys have any experience like this issue? i hope i can get some good advice from any REDIS expert here. Thank you.

Below is the code to connect to redis

Public Class RedisConnectionPool
        Private Shared redisMaster As ConnectionMultiplexer = Nothing
        Private Shared serializer As NewtonsoftSerializer = Nothing

```
    Private Shared _lazyConnectionExt As Lazy(Of StackExchangeRedisCacheClient)

    Public Shared CacheClient As StackExchangeRedisCacheClient

    Shared Sub New()

        serializer = New NewtonsoftSerializer()

        Dim configs As New ConfigurationOptions

        With configs
            .EndPoints.Add(RedisConfig.EndPoints)
            .ClientName = RedisConfig.ClientName
            .KeepAlive = 120
            .ConnectTimeout = RedisConfig.ConnectionTimeout
            .SyncTimeout = RedisConfig.SyncTimeout
            .AllowAdmin = RedisConfig.AllowAdmin
            .Password = RedisConfig.Password
            .AbortOnConnectFail = RedisConfig.AbortOnConnectFail
            .DefaultDatabase = 0
        End With
        redisMaster = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configs)

        _lazyConnectionExt = New Lazy(Of StackExchangeRedisCacheClient)(Function()
                                                                            Return New StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(redisMaster, serializer)
                                                                        End Function)

        CacheClient = _lazyConnectionExt.Value
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Can you post the script which connects to redis ?

Comment: hi sooraj, the server cannot handle when it reach this total of connection. jurin@ubuntu16RedisDB:~$ netstat -an|grep 6379|wc -l
4065

Comment: Is that real traffic? I am assuming your client is creating connections and not closing it properly.

Comment: I think what u said is correct..but i am not sure how to deal with the redis connection properly. After creating connection the tcp is still there,that is why i try to increase the tcp keep alive. I dont have any idea on how to close it properly. Sorry i am really new on this redis.

Comment: You are creating new connections here: New StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(redisMaster, serializer) . Just create it outside and use the same object.